# How can i format/convert the date "20200415" to 2020-04-15?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

How can i format/convert the date "20200415" to 2020-04-15?
string date = "20200415";

the output should 2020-04-15

Comment: there are tousands of similar questions. Did you even search for that before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't make string manipulation - my approach with parsing the date with a formated output in a second step:

```
string date = "20200415";
DateTime dtTemp = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", null);
string result = dtTemp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```